# I am getting an error in ionic 3 : Runtime Error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when posting to php from ionic3

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

this is the php code, here i am requesting the username and password from ionic 3 to do a select query if there is data in my sql i will return to ionic 3 accepted and if not , rejected this is for the login page.

```
$Username= filter_var($_REQUEST['Username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
$Password   = filter_var($_REQUEST['Password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
$sql="SELECT Username, Password FROM doctoradd WHERE Username = :Username AND Password = :Password";
         //$sql  = "INSERT INTO technologies(name, description) VALUES(:Username, :Password)";
         $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindParam(':Username', $Username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(':Password', $Password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();
        while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
        // Assign each row of data to associative array
        $data[] = $row;
        }
        if($data == []){
            echo json_encode("null");
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode("accepted");

        }
```

my ionic 3 code : this is the on button click function

```
let Username  : string = this.form.controls["Username"].value,
 Password   : string    = this.form.controls["Password"].value;

     let body     : string   = "Username=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password,
     type     : string   = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     headers  : any      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type}),
     options  : any      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }),
     url      : any      = this.baseURI + "sign-in.php";

 this.http.post(url, body, options)
 .subscribe((data) =>
 {
    // If the request was successful notify the user
    // if(data.status === 200)
    // {
    //    //this.hideForm   = true;

    //    this.toast.create({
    //     message: 'Welcome ',
    //     duration:3000


    //           }).present();
    //    //this.sendNotification(`Congratulations the technology: ${username} was successfully added`);



    // }
    // // Otherwise let 'em know anyway
    // else
    // {
    //    //this.sendNotification('Something went wrong!');
    //    this.toast.create({
    //     message: 'Wrong Username or Password',
    //     duration:3000


    //           }).present();

    // }



 });


 this.SignIn();
```

}

the signin function where i want to retrieve the json_encode in the php if it is accepted or not

```
SignIn(){
 this.http.get('http://localhost:10080/testdb/sign-in.php')
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(data => 
 {
    this.items = data; 
 });
 alert(this.items);
 if(this.items=="accepted"){
  this.navCtrl.push('ExamplePage',this.username);
 }
 else{
  this.toast.create({
    message: 'Wrong Username or Password',
    duration:3000
          }).present();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This error happens in the mapping function. the response u get is not in a JSON format, so you can not map it to res.json()

check your response in Postman or some Tool . if not eliminate the map function and check the response;

```
SignIn(){
 this.http.get('http://localhost:10080/testdb/sign-in.php')
 .map(res => res)
 .subscribe(data => 
 {
    console.log(res);
   // this.items = data; 
 });
 alert(this.items);
 if(this.items=="accepted"){
  this.navCtrl.push('ExamplePage',this.username);
 }
 else{
  this.toast.create({
    message: 'Wrong Username or Password',
    duration:3000
          }).present();
 }
```

Comment: i just removed the .map and it stopped giving me the error but "this.items" is giving a null value when clicking the button but the two input values are in the database can you help me with this !! thank youu

Comment: can you console log your response and send me ?

Comment: console.log(res) is giving an error : Cannot find name 'res'. can i use it without the .map? i used it without it but this.items is giving null value on button click can you help with this?

Comment: console.log(data)

Comment: output for console.log(data): Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:10080/testdb/sign-in.php